# Redirect to login after 401 in Angular / Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, error-handling

I have a service that handles my http responses and ideally, I'd like to set it up such that whenever a 401 error status is received, the user is sent to the login page.  I understand that you should not perform routing from within a service, but I am hoping there is a pattern that is acceptable since I would like to catch all 401s.

```
@Injectable()

export class ResponseHandlerService implements OnInit {

  options: object;
  headers: any;

  constructor(
    private clientService: ClientService,
    private globalVarService: GlobalVariablesProvider,
    private toastCtrl: ToastController
    private navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headers = new Headers();
  }

  getOptions() {
    return this.globalVarService.getAuthToken().subscribe( token => {
      this.headers.append("authentication", token);
      this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    })
  }

  extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || body || { };
  }

  private handleError = (error: Response | any) => {
    let errMsg: string;
    console.log("Error: ", error)
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      let body = error['_body'].substring(0, 200)
      console.log(body)
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} to ${error.url} - ${body}`
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }

    if ( error.status == 401 ) {
      this.clientService.handleResponse("Invalid authentication - Please sign in again")

      // does not work. states navCtrl has no provider
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage)
    }

    console.log(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass "ROUTER_PROVIDERS" as provider and inject router in your ResponseHandlerService then it will work.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
   ResponseHandlerService
]);
```

Comment: In Ionic we don't use the general angular router

Comment: This works with Angular, Other option you have is to use events and listen that event in component and use NavControler from component to change route.

Answer (score -1):

You could inject Angular's router service `private router: Router` and whenever you receive a 401 status on your login, just do

`this.router.navigate(['/your-login-route']);`

Comment: That is what he is doing! `NavController` basically is the router in Ionic.